# How to set SUPER privilege for a database

Tags: mysql

When I import data and got below problem(error-1) When I try to google it and from the link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html#grant-privileges I check out Global Privileges and use this id dql editor - GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'dev-1'@'localhost'; Which give me error -2

```
error-1
SQL query: 


/*!50001 CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED */
/*!50013 DEFINER=`ars_user465`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER */
/*!50001 VIEW `constantcontact_customers_agents` AS select `customers`.`CustomerID` AS `CustomerID`,`customers`.`AgentID` AS `AgentID`,`customers`.`AccountType` AS `CustomerAccountType`,`customers`.`FirstName` AS `CustomerFirstName`,`customers`.`LastName` AS `CustomerLastName`,`customers`.`Address` AS `CustomerAddress`,`customers`.`City` AS `CustomerCity`,`customers`.`State` AS `CustomerState`,`customers`.`Zip` AS `CustomerZip`,`customers`.`Phone` AS `CustomerPhone`,`customers`.`Cell` AS `CustomerCell`,`customers`.`Fax` AS `CustomerFax`,`customers`.`Email` AS `CustomerEmail`,`customers`.`Dob` AS `CustomerDob`,`agents`.`FirstName` AS `AgentFirstName`,`agents`.`LastName` AS `AgentLastName`,`agents`.`CompanyName` AS `AgentCompanyName`,`agents`.`ApiUsername` AS `ApiUsername`,`agents`.`ApiPassword` AS `ApiPassword` from (`customers` join `agents` on((`customers`.`AgentID` = `agents`.`AgentID`)[...]

MySQL said: 
#1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation 

error -2 :

#1045 - Access denied for user 'dev-1'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 0):

error1: The user you are logged in with needs the `super` privilege.

> Error: 1227 SQLSTATE: 42000 (ER_SPECIFIC_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR) Message:
>   Access denied; you need the %s privilege for this operation

error2: Most likely, the user you are logged in with (dev-1@%) doesn't have the `Grant` privilege.

Run `SELECT USER(), CURRENT_USER();` to confirm you are logged in as the user you think you are.

Then run `SELECT user,host,grant_priv from mysql.user where grant_priv = 'Y';` To confirm if that user has the `GRANT` privilege. If not you will need to log as a user with the `GRANT` privilege to assign the `super` privilege. (quite often these users are `localhost` only be default).